# How to drop a row in Pandas only if it exists in the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that sometimes has a row called (UnSpecified) and sometimes don't. When I try to drop the row by the name and it doesn't exist I get a "(UnSpecified) not found in axis" error.

```py
### sales 2018 ###

sales_2018 = pd.read_csv('sales 2018.csv')

# gross sales

gross_sales_2018_pivot = pd.DataFrame(pd.pivot_table(sales_2018, values=['GROSS SALES'], index=['DAYPARTNAME'], columns=['DAY OF WEEK'], aggfunc=np.sum))

gross_sales_2018_pivot = gross_sales_2018_pivot.drop('(UnSpecified)', axis=0)                       

gross_sales_2018_pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='overall')
writer.save()
```

How can I create a loop to make it ignore/pass the error if there is no (UnSpecified) row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
gross_sales_2018_pivot = gross_sales_2018_pivot.drop('(UnSpecified)', axis=0, errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

gross_sales_2018_pivot = gross_sales_2018_pivot.loc[*condition for not unspecified*, :]

Example:

`gross_sales_2018_pivot = gross_sales_2018_pivot.loc[gross_sales_2018_pivot['important_col'] != 'trash', :]`